# Javascript RTE with spellcheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, editor, rte

Can anyone point me in the direction of a good rich text editor (cost not an issue) that has an inbuilt spell check or can be configured to point to an internal spelling service.
I cannot use widgets that harness external jsonp services (google api etc) due to the application residing on a restricted network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) is a solid RTE that can use ASpell or PSpell for its spell checking plugin

Comment: I have gone with tinymce and a custom service using hunspell and open office dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

You could easily build a spell check into your choice editor with the aspell. There should be a library for your choice of server language.

http://aspell.net/

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Spell-Check](http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/demo_wysiwyg.asp) claims to be able to integrate easily with other RTEs. In fact, they even have a page showing you how to integrate them, with a live demo. Personally, I would stick to a tried and true RTE like YUI's or WMD (used on SO) and tack on a spell-checker, like this one.

Comment: javascriptspellcheck.com is a dead link